# Jquery Ajax POST request with parameters in Rails (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make ajax post request in rails application. But i am getting error in response.

Rails code:-

```
def search_exams(myparam1 , myparam2)
   json_data = {:aaData=> [["abc","xyz","lmnop"],["sdf","adsdf","sadfsd"],["sdf","adsdf","sadfsd"]]}.to_json
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render :json => json_data }
   end
end
```

Script Code:-

```
<%= javascript_tag "window._token = '#{form_authenticity_token}'" %>


<script>
$.ajax({
        url:'/home/search_exams',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            myparam1: "First Param value",
            myparam2: "Second param value",
            authenticity_token: window._token
        },
        success:function(data){
            debugger;
        },
        error:function(data){
            debugger;
        }
    });
  </script>
```

I am getting this error:-

"ArgumentError in HomeController#search_exams wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) Rails.root: C:/Users/........"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def search_exams
```

Remove arguments from the method.

When you pass a request with params to a Rails controller, the middleware stack puts them into the `params` hash, so you'll get:

```
params[:param1]
params[:params2]
```

--

You'll also want to consider making your JS [unobtrusive](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("action", ".element", function(){
     $.ajax({
        url:'/home/search_exams',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            myparam1: "First Param value",
            myparam2: "Second param value",
            authenticity_token: window._token
        },
        success:function(data){
            debugger;
        },
        error:function(data){
            debugger;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ohh.. Thank you Rich Peck.

Comment: Updating answer for you